# After deployment, login control stops working

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-4.0, login-control, login-attempts

In my development environment I can register and login just fine. After loging in or registering I do a redirect. Once deployed I noticed that the registering still works, but the page refreshes. Stranger still is the fact that when I try to log in, it also refreshes.

So basically, everything works - users still can register, the application can find the database, I can view public pages, etc. Just getting past the login (or register) page is not working. No redirect, just a refresh...

I run in IIS 6.0, SQL Server 2008, asp.net 4.0. I use membership and roles provided by asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information, my best guess is a web.config problem.  Make sure defaultUrl attribute set to your default page's name in the [forms element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) of the web.config.

Comment: Well, there's really not any more info. On development everything worked. On production as well, I can see the application, db connections are made, and nothing else has changed. The redirect is in tact from the development. I mean, if redirect works on dev., it should work on production as well, right?

Comment: You said "*I* do a redirect". Are you manually redirecting or are you letting the Login control do it for you?  Did you double-check the web.config settings in production to make sure they're correct?  I know the Login control works properly in production environments, so I'm guessing it's a configuration issue.

Comment: Right. I do a redirect manually. I have a file (Redirect.aspx) that redirects for me. In the login.aspx page, I have this: DestinationPageUrl="~/Redirect.aspx". This was done so I could redirect based on roles. Now that I think of it... I did a restore of the database, and somewhere I read that all of the info that got into the db on the dev. could be broken. I'm thinking now... might it be because it doesn't know the roles? Because the roles defined in the db are from still from the dev. and it isn't working anymore?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable thing to investigate.